# IBM Decimal to C# datetime

Tags: c#, parsing, datetime

I have a datetime, which came from a DB2 database, now I'm trying to convert it to a C# datetime.

```
Datetime.ParseExact(requestedate.ToString(), "yyyyMMdd", System.Globalization.CultureInfo.InvariantCulture);
```

It works perfect, until a user didn't filled out the form correctly and the requestedate is "0" in the database.
I can do it like:

```
Datetime paresedRequestedate;
    Try 
    { 
       paresedRequestedate = Datetime.ParseExact(requestedate.ToString(), "yyyyMMdd", System.Globalization.CultureInfo.InvariantCulture);
    } 
    catch(exception) 
    { 
       paresedRequestedate = default(DateTime);
    }
```

But I was learned not to do this kind of things in a catch. So is there a beter way to do this?

Comment: Tryed TryParse() but get each time the default datetime. Instead of the correct date

Comment: if(DateTime.TryParse....) you have parsed the datestring, else wrong Format.

Comment: Like I said before, when I use TryParse everytime it returns a default DateTime, instead of the correct date.
In other words, the parsing fails

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Try to use [`TryParseExact`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.datetime.tryparseexact%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) - you'll get the same result with cleaner code.

Comment: I missed that methode I think :) Tnx